# Sort values in table - PHP

Tags: php, html, twig

I want sort the values in my table `HTML.Twig` in `Decreasing order`
This one  the function `PHP` to fill the table:

```
public function getWidgetData(){
            $tab_article = ['A', 'B', 'C',.......];

        $ret = $this->getOldDate().'#'.$this->getNewdate()..............;
        $ret = $ret.'#'.count($tab_article);
        $data = 0;          
        for($i=0; $i<count($tab_article); $i++) {
            $dataOld=  explode('##', $this->_customer->getTurnover('Réparation', NULL, $tab_article[$i], $this->_oldDate, NULL));
            $dataNew=  explode('##', $this->_customer->getTurnover('Réparation', NULL, $tab_article[$i], $this->_newDate, NULL));

                $data = $this->differencePercentage1($dataOld[0],$dataNew[0]);

            if($dataOld[0]!=0){
                $ret = $ret.'#'.$tab_article[$i].'#'.$dataOld[0].'#'.$dataNew[0].'#'.$data."%";
            }
            else{
                $ret = $ret.'#'.$tab_article[$i].'#'.$dataOld[0].'#'.$dataNew[0].'#'."+".$data."$USD";
            }
        }
        return $ret;
```

And this following the code `HTML.Twig`

```
                       <tbody>
                        {% for elemt in widget %}
                            {% if loop.index>17 and loop.index<17+(4*widget[17]) and loop.index+3<widget|length %}
                                {% if (loop.index-2) is divisible by(4) %}
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <td>{{widget[loop.index]|raw}}</td>
                                        <td>{{widget[loop.index+1]|raw}}</td>
                                        <td>{{widget[loop.index+2]|raw}}</td>     // I want sort this value in Decreasing order
                                        <td>{{widget[loop.index+3]|raw}}</td>
                                      </tr>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
```

The variable who is I want sort it Decreasing order in the function `PHP` is `$dataNew`

How can I do it please.

Comment: Why don't you sort the array in the controller?

Comment: So I should do it in the function above ? because it's in the controller. Or you mean that I should create a new function in the controller and I call it in HTML.Twig ??

Comment: Before returning your array with data you could run it through a custom sort function with [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: Shold I add just this one uasort($ret, $datanew); ?? because I added it just before the returning my array it returned an error $datanew must be String.  or I should create another function ?

Comment: I think that I should use arsort(); because I want sort the table according the value of $newdata. What you think please.